# PHP get all links and images with preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

from news website we have many tag like with :

```
<a class="picLink" target="_blank" href="/EN/news/397423/MY-TEST-NEWS">
   <img class="fr" width="115" style="margin:6px 0px 0px 8px;width: 115px;" src="http://sample.com/files/EN/news/369326_276.jpg" alt="MY TEST NEWS !">
</a>
```

i want to get `href` and image `src` and `alt` attribute values from that.

my simple code do not correct:

```
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
<?php
error_reporting(1);
$handle='http://sample.com';
$handle = file_get_contents($handle);
preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+class="titr1y"[^>] href="(.*?)"*><img class="[^>]" width="[^>]" style="[^>]" src="(.*?)" alt="(.*?)"*><\/a>/si', $handle, $matching_data);

print_r($matching_data);
?>
```

please help me to correct that.

Comment: People always say, don't use regex to parse HTML. Sometimes people are right. [There are free tools to parse HTML.](https://www.google.nl/search?q=php+parse+html)

Comment: Don't use regexs. Use a dom parser: http://php.net/dom

Comment: Is it required to use REGEXP? I may have some easier solution if not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get it with this

```
$re = '/(alt|href|src)=("[^"]*")/'; 
$str = '<a class="picLink" target="_blank" href="/EN/news/397423/MY-TEST-NEWS">\n   <img class="fr" width="115" style="margin:6px 0px 0px 8px;width: 115px;" src="http://sample.com/files/EN/news/369326_276.jpg" alt="MY TEST NEWS !">\n</a>\n<a class="picLink" target="_blank" href="/EN/news/397423/MY-TEST-NEWS">\n   <img class="fr" width="115" style="margin:6px 0px 0px 8px;width: 115px;" src="http://sample.com/files/EN/news/369326_276.jpg" alt="MY TEST NEWS !">\n</a>'; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**output**

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => href="/EN/news/397423/MY-TEST-NEWS"
            [1] => src="http://sample.com/files/EN/news/369326_276.jpg"
            [2] => alt="MY TEST NEWS !"
            [3] => href="/EN/news/397423/MY-TEST-NEWS"
            [4] => src="http://sample.com/files/EN/news/369326_276.jpg"
            [5] => alt="MY TEST NEWS !"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => href
            [1] => src
            [2] => alt
            [3] => href
            [4] => src
            [5] => alt
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "/EN/news/397423/MY-TEST-NEWS"
            [1] => "http://sample.com/files/EN/news/369326_276.jpg"
            [2] => "MY TEST NEWS !"
            [3] => "/EN/news/397423/MY-TEST-NEWS"
            [4] => "http://sample.com/files/EN/news/369326_276.jpg"
            [5] => "MY TEST NEWS !"
        )

)
```

in array[2] you'll get the desired values

Comment: Why the quotes inside the capture group?